# Is there a point in putting "resume enclosed" on cover letter?

Tags: resume, cover-letter

When I learned about cover letter writing I was taught to put at the bottom of the cover letter "Encl.: Resume (2 pages)"

Do people still do this or is it largely obsolete with online applications? I started adding more contact information to the bottom of my cover letter and now things are getting messed up. Should "Encl.: Resume (2 pages)" be the VERY last thing on the cover letter, after phone number, email address, linkedin etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe so.  It's a formal way of saying "please see attached [as you would in an email] to alert the reader that there is more to look at.

An astute professional will also understand that you may be knowledgeable of business etiquette.  This is particularly useful when applying for roles that involve client/customer contact.

Hope this helps Jimmy!

Comment: Modern correspondence has become so informal that people unfortunately let this carry-over to the job application process. This is a good way to separate yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases when you apply the cover letter and resume will be separate documents loaded onto a webpage. They are unlikely to ever be in the same envelope, nor will they be part of the same document.

It is not required on most cover letters, but if they are being submitted in the same envelope it can't hurt to include the line mentioning that the resume is enclosed.

Answer (score -2):

I don't bother with what you're doing any more that I bother with salutations. Saves me both the kind of headache you're having and the kind of headache that those who are trying to figure out whom to address the communication to  are having. I have other things on my mind that are more important.

I can't understand why you are adding your contact info at the end of your cover letter when the same info is - or should be, on your resume.

Comment: So you can't understand why having contact info in multiple places is a good thing?